# Operator overloading confusion in Java

Tags: java, operator-overloading

Though we all know that Java doesn't support operator overloading, then why is the `+` operator an arithmetic operator as well as `String` concatenation operator.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java doesn't allow *custom* operator overloading. Several operators, not just `+`, are overloaded *by specification*, and that's the way they stay.

The main issue with custom operator overloading is the opaqueness and unpredictability of their semantics, contributing to the probability of massive WTF moments while reading (and even writing) code.

Comment: The ability it be able to read java sources and know what operators does without having to read other source files first, is a very good thing in my opinion

Comment: Imagine a language where `,` is an overloadable operator---but wait, no need to imagine :)

Answer (score 0):

When we use `+` with strings, compiler actually convert them to use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: This is not specified behavior. The compiler *may* compile with `StringBuilder`, but is not required to.

Comment: Yes Marko, you are right, its not a standard, but most of the compilers will replace custom overloading with StringBuilder.

Comment: In case of compiletime constants like `"foo"+"bar"` `+` will not be replaced by `StringBuilder` but compiler will change this code to `"foobar"`.

Comment: The larger point is that, since this question doesn't in any aspect deal with optimizations that compilers may perform, this answer doesn't really go very far in addressing it.

Comment: I can name only two for now, `javac` and `Eclipse Java compiler` :)

Comment: I think Thorbjorn carefully (and slyly) chose the number 3 :)

Comment: @chrylis it appears that the gnu java project did not have critical mass anymore after IBM left Apache Harmony (which was the biggest user of GNU Classpath).  The web site says it is Java 1.4 with a bit of Java 5, which does not have StringBuilder.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Is `StringBuilder` really that new? *checks* *feels old*

Comment: Java 6 came out in 2006.